# CAPSPageMenu swift

Tags: swift

Hi I'm using [CAPSPageMenu](https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu) and I have 3 viewControllers, the first one is the pageMenu that display the 2 others [Controller1 & Controller2]. But I want my first viewController to be the one that display my second VC without using an empty viewController to append the viewControllers. It's hard to explain.

So here's what I mean:

here's My CAPSPageMenu (I don't want it):

```
class PageMenuVC: UIViewController {
    var pageMenu : CAPSPageMenu?

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    var controllerArray : [UIViewController] = []
    
    //let controller1 : SearchArtistVC = SearchArtistVC(nibName: "SearchArtistVC", bundle: nil)

    let controller1 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchVC")
    controllerArray.append(controller1!)

    let controller2 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "test")
    controllerArray.append(controller2!)
    
    // Customize menu (Optional)
    let parameters: [CAPSPageMenuOption] = [
        .scrollMenuBackgroundColor(UIColor(red: 30.0/255.0, green: 30.0/255.0, blue: 30.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)),
        .viewBackgroundColor(UIColor(red: 20.0/255.0, green: 20.0/255.0, blue: 20.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)),
        .selectionIndicatorColor(UIColor.orange),
        .bottomMenuHairlineColor(UIColor(red: 70.0/255.0, green: 70.0/255.0, blue: 80.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)),
        .menuItemFont(UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 13.0)!),
        .menuHeight(40.0),
        .menuItemWidth(90.0),
        .centerMenuItems(true)
    ]
    
    // Initialize scroll menu
    pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height), pageMenuOptions: nil)
    
    self.addChildViewController(pageMenu!)
    self.view.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)
    pageMenu!.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

I want Controller1 to be my PageMenu and I want controller1 to also show in the menu items.
If you have questions or don't understand, please ask.

Comment: i have used this can u share screenshot@John